# matching time a time in the interval between a start and end time

Tags: datetime, r, time

Fellow R users of StackOverflow-

I have to match a set of distinct times to intervals of time defined in another data frame by a start and end. This would result in one data frame with a many to one relation.

A simplified set of the records to match into follows:

```
       vid               start                 end
17599 7588 2011-02-14 19:00:00 2011-02-14 19:11:00
17601 7588 2011-02-14 19:58:00 2011-02-14 20:43:00
17603 7588 2011-02-14 21:22:00 2011-02-14 22:00:00
```

And some example records to match to the above data are:

```
        vid            datetime
469818 7588 2011-02-14 19:00:10
470747 7588 2011-02-14 19:59:10
470788 7588 2011-02-14 21:23:10
```

What I would like is something like:

```
        vid            datetime               start                 end
        7588 2011-02-14 19:00:10 2011-02-14 19:00:00 2011-02-14 19:11:00
        7588 2011-02-14 19:59:10 2011-02-14 19:58:00 2011-02-14 20:43:00
        7588 2011-02-14 21:23:10 2011-02-14 21:22:00 2011-02-14 22:00:00
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this in R. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did, however solve the problem, using >= and <= operators to compare the start, end and datetime fields, after splitting the data using split(). ;`match.col = with(d2[[v]], d1$datetime >= d2.start & d1$datetime <= d2.end)`

Answer (score 1):

Reproducible example:

```
txt1 <- "       vid               start                 end
17599 7588 '2011-02-14 19:00:00' '2011-02-14 19:11:00'
17601 7588 '2011-02-14 19:58:00' '2011-02-14 20:43:00'
17603 7588 '2011-02-14 21:22:00' '2011-02-14 22:00:00'
"
txt2 <- "        vid            datetime
469818 7588 '2011-02-14 19:00:10'
470747 7588 '2011-02-14 19:59:10'
470788 7588 '2011-02-14 21:23:10'
"
d1 <- read.table(textConnection(txt1), header = TRUE,
                 colClasses = c("integer","integer","POSIXct","POSIXct"))
d2 <- read.table(textConnection(txt2), header = TRUE,
                 colClasses = c("integer","integer","POSIXct"))
```

We can get the indexes (rows) in `d1` that correspond to each row of `d2` using:

```
> idx <- sapply(d2$datetime, 
+               function(x, start, end) {which(x > start & x < end)}, 
+               d1$start, d1$end)
> idx
[1] 1 2 3
```

And we can use the indexes `idx` to bind elements of `d1` on to `d2`:

```
> cbind(d2, d1[idx, 2:3])
        vid            datetime               start                 end
469818 7588 2011-02-14 19:00:10 2011-02-14 19:00:00 2011-02-14 19:11:00
470747 7588 2011-02-14 19:59:10 2011-02-14 19:58:00 2011-02-14 20:43:00
470788 7588 2011-02-14 21:23:10 2011-02-14 21:22:00 2011-02-14 22:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Gavin. Perhaps I wasn't clear in my initial statement, but I needed a many-to-one match and the data is not guaranteed to sort as well as my example did.

I did, however solve the problem, using >= and <= operators to compare the start, end and datetime fields. 

match.col = with(d2[[v]], d1$datetime >= d2.start & d1$datetime <= d2.end);