# Check if Posixct time is within interval

Tags: r, count, intervals, lubridate

The problem:
I have two dataframes that I would like to merge depending on the date/time of one dataframe being in the interval of the other dataframe.

traffic: Date and Time (Posixct), Frequency

mydata: Interval, Sum of Frequency

I would now like to calculate if the Posixct time from traffic is within the interval of mydata and if this is TRUE I would like to count the frequency in the column "Sum of Frequencies" in mydata.

The two problems, that I encountered:
1. traffic data frame has significantly more rows than mydata. I dont know how to tell R to loop through every observation in traffic to check for one row in mydata.

2. There can be more than one observation fitting in the frequency interval of mydata. I want R to add up all frequencies of the different traffic observations to get a total score of frequencies. Also the intervals are overlapping.

Here is the data:

```
DateTime <- c("2014-11-01 04:00:00", "2014-11-01 04:03:00",  "2014-11-01 04:06:00", "2014-11-01 04:08:00", "2014-11-01 04:10:00", "2014-11-01 04:12:00", "2015-08-01 04:13:00", "2015-08-01 04:45:00", "2015-08-01 14:15:00", "2015-08-01 14:13:00")
DateTime <- as.POSIXct(DateTime)
Frequency <- c(1,2,3,5,12,1,2,2,1,1)                 
traffic <- data.frame(DateTime, Frequency)

library(lubridate)
DateTime1 <- c("2014-11-01 04:00:00", "2015-08-01 04:03:00",  "2015-08-01 14:00:00")
DateTime2 <- c("2014-11-01 04:15:00", "2015-08-01 04:13:00",  "2015-08-01 14:15:00")
DateTime1 <- as.POSIXct(DateTime1)
DateTime2 <- as.POSIXct(DateTime2)
mydata <- data.frame(DateTime1, DateTime2)
mydata$Interval <- as.interval(DateTime1, DateTime2)
mydata$SumFrequency <- NA
```

The expected outcome should be something like this:

```
mydata$SumFrequency <- c(24, 2, 2)
head(mydata)
```

I tried int_overlaps from package lubridate.
Any tips on how to solve this are higly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short solution with `foverlaps` from the *data.table* package:

```
mydata <- data.table(DateTime1, DateTime2, key = c("DateTime1", "DateTime2"))
traffic <- data.table(start = DateTime, end = DateTime, Frequency, key = c("start","end"))

foverlaps(traffic, mydata, type="within", nomatch=0L)[, .(sumFreq = sum(Frequency)), 
                                                      by = .(DateTime1, DateTime2)]
```

which gives:

```
             DateTime1           DateTime2 sumFreq
1: 2014-11-01 04:00:00 2014-11-01 04:15:00      24
2: 2015-08-01 04:03:00 2015-08-01 04:13:00       2
3: 2015-08-01 14:00:00 2015-08-01 14:15:00       2
```

Answer (score 4):

On a `data.table` approach with `between` to filter traffic dataset on time:

```
setDT(traffic)
setDT(mydata)

mydata[,SumFrequency := as.numeric(SumFrequency)] # coerce logical to numeric for next step.
mydata[,SumFrequency := sum( traffic[ DateTime %between% c(DateTime1, DateTime2), Frequency] ), by=1:nrow(mydata)]
```

which give:

```
             DateTime1           DateTime2                                           Interval SumFrequency
1: 2014-11-01 04:00:00 2014-11-01 04:15:00   2014-11-01 04:00:00 CET--2014-11-01 04:15:00 CET           24
2: 2015-08-01 04:03:00 2015-08-01 04:13:00 2015-08-01 04:03:00 CEST--2015-08-01 04:13:00 CEST            2
3: 2015-08-01 14:00:00 2015-08-01 14:15:00 2015-08-01 14:00:00 CEST--2015-08-01 14:15:00 CEST            2
```

If there's a lot of row in mydata, it could be better to create an index column and use it in by clause:

```
mydata[, idx := .I]
mydata[, SumFrequency := sum( traffic[DateTime %between% c(DateTime1, DateTime2),Frequency] ),by=idx]
```

And this gives:

```
             DateTime1           DateTime2                                           Interval SumFrequency idx
1: 2014-11-01 04:00:00 2014-11-01 04:15:00   2014-11-01 04:00:00 CET--2014-11-01 04:15:00 CET           24   1
2: 2015-08-01 04:03:00 2015-08-01 04:13:00 2015-08-01 04:03:00 CEST--2015-08-01 04:13:00 CEST            2   2
3: 2015-08-01 14:00:00 2015-08-01 14:15:00 2015-08-01 14:00:00 CEST--2015-08-01 14:15:00 CEST            2   3
```

Answer (score 3):

I see two solutions :

### With `data.frame` and `plyr`

You could do it using `%within%` function in `lubridate` and with a for-loop or using `plyr` loop functions like `dlply`

```
DateTime <- c("2014-11-01 04:00:00", "2014-11-01 04:03:00",  "2014-11-01 04:06:00", "2014-11-01 04:08:00", "2014-11-01 04:10:00", "2014-11-01 04:12:00", "2015-08-01 04:13:00", "2015-08-01 04:45:00", "2015-08-01 14:15:00", "2015-08-01 14:13:00")
DateTime <- as.POSIXct(DateTime)
Frequency <- c(1,2,3,5,12,1,2,2,1,1)                 
traffic <- data.frame(DateTime, Frequency)

library(lubridate)
DateTime1 <- c("2014-11-01 04:00:00", "2015-08-01 04:03:00",  "2015-08-01 14:00:00")
DateTime2 <- c("2014-11-01 04:15:00", "2015-08-01 04:13:00",  "2015-08-01 14:15:00")
DateTime1 <- as.POSIXct(DateTime1)
DateTime2 <- as.POSIXct(DateTime2)
mydata <- data.frame(DateTime1, DateTime2)
mydata$Interval <- as.interval(DateTime1, DateTime2)

library(plyr)
# Create a group-by variable
mydata$NumInt <- 1:nrow(mydata)
mydata$SumFrequency <- dlply(mydata, .(NumInt),
                             function(row){
                               sum(
                                 traffic[traffic$DateTime %within% row$Interval, "Frequency"]
                               )
                             })

mydata
#>             DateTime1           DateTime2
#> 1 2014-11-01 04:00:00 2014-11-01 04:15:00
#> 2 2015-08-01 04:03:00 2015-08-01 04:13:00
#> 3 2015-08-01 14:00:00 2015-08-01 14:15:00
#>                                             Interval NumInt SumFrequency
#> 1   2014-11-01 04:00:00 CET--2014-11-01 04:15:00 CET      1           24
#> 2 2015-08-01 04:03:00 CEST--2015-08-01 04:13:00 CEST      2            2
#> 3 2015-08-01 14:00:00 CEST--2015-08-01 14:15:00 CEST      3            2
```

---

### With `data.table` and functions `foverlaps`

`data.table` has implemented a function for overlapping joins that you could use in your case with a little trick.
This functions is `foverlaps` (I uses below `data.table 1.9.6`)
(see [How to perform join over date ranges using data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487949/how-to-perform-join-over-date-ranges-using-data-table) [and this presentation](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/talks/EARL2014_OverlapRangeJoin_Arun.pdf))

Notice that you do not need to create interval with `lubridate`

```
DateTime <- c("2014-11-01 04:00:00", "2014-11-01 04:03:00",  "2014-11-01 04:06:00", "2014-11-01 04:08:00", "2014-11-01 04:10:00", "2014-11-01 04:12:00", "2015-08-01 04:13:00", "2015-08-01 04:45:00", "2015-08-01 14:15:00", "2015-08-01 14:13:00")
DateTime <- as.POSIXct(DateTime)
Frequency <- c(1,2,3,5,12,1,2,2,1,1)                 
traffic <- data.table(DateTime, Frequency)

library(lubridate)
DateTime1 <- c("2014-11-01 04:00:00", "2015-08-01 04:03:00",  "2015-08-01 14:00:00")
DateTime2 <- c("2014-11-01 04:15:00", "2015-08-01 04:13:00",  "2015-08-01 14:15:00")
mydata <- data.table(DateTime1 = as.POSIXct(DateTime1), DateTime2 = as.POSIXct(DateTime2))

# Use function `foverlaps`  for overlapping joins

# Here's the trick : create a dummy variable to artificially have an interval
traffic[, dummy:=DateTime]
setkey(mydata, DateTime1, DateTime2)

# do the join
mydata2 <- foverlaps(traffic, mydata, by.x=c("DateTime", "dummy"), type ="within", nomatch=0L)[, dummy := NULL][]
mydata2
#>              DateTime1           DateTime2            DateTime Frequency
#> 1: 2014-11-01 04:00:00 2014-11-01 04:15:00 2014-11-01 04:00:00         1
#> 2: 2014-11-01 04:00:00 2014-11-01 04:15:00 2014-11-01 04:03:00         2
#> 3: 2014-11-01 04:00:00 2014-11-01 04:15:00 2014-11-01 04:06:00         3
#> 4: 2014-11-01 04:00:00 2014-11-01 04:15:00 2014-11-01 04:08:00         5
#> 5: 2014-11-01 04:00:00 2014-11-01 04:15:00 2014-11-01 04:10:00        12
#> 6: 2014-11-01 04:00:00 2014-11-01 04:15:00 2014-11-01 04:12:00         1
#> 7: 2015-08-01 04:03:00 2015-08-01 04:13:00 2015-08-01 04:13:00         2
#> 8: 2015-08-01 14:00:00 2015-08-01 14:15:00 2015-08-01 14:15:00         1
#> 9: 2015-08-01 14:00:00 2015-08-01 14:15:00 2015-08-01 14:13:00         1

# summarise with a sum by grouping by each line of mydata
setkeyv(mydata2, key(mydata))
mydata2[mydata, .(SumFrequency = sum(Frequency)), by = .EACHI]
#>              DateTime1           DateTime2 SumFrequency
#> 1: 2014-11-01 04:00:00 2014-11-01 04:15:00           24
#> 2: 2015-08-01 04:03:00 2015-08-01 04:13:00            2
#> 3: 2015-08-01 14:00:00 2015-08-01 14:15:00            2
```

Comment: your `foverlaps` solution is pretty long-winded, see my answer on how to make it a lot shorter

Comment: no need to update your answer, that would make them identical which isn't the purpose imo

Answer (score 1):

As far as point 2 is concerned you can use aggregate for instance

```
aggData <- aggregate(traffic$Frequency~format(traffic$DateTime, "%Y%m%d h:m"), data=traffic, sum)
```

This sums all frequencies in minute intervals.

And for point 1. Wouldn't a merge work?

```
merge(x = myData, y = aggData, by = "DateTime", all.x = TRUE)
```

The outer merge is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: There is no need for explicit calls to variables if you are using the `data` argument in `aggregate`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work. The traffic data is already aggregated to the point of aggreagtion that I need. I want to aggregate the frequencies of different rows once the calculation determines that several of the data points are within an interval. When using merge it adds the Frequency column, but only returns NAs.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `for.loop` we could do something like this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(mydata)) {
  mydata$SumFrequency[i] <- sum(traffic$Frequency[traffic$DateTime %within% mydata$Interval[i]])
}

> mydata
#            DateTime1           DateTime2                                           Interval SumFrequency
#1 2014-11-01 04:00:00 2014-11-01 04:15:00   2014-11-01 04:00:00 CET--2014-11-01 04:15:00 CET           24
#2 2015-08-01 04:03:00 2015-08-01 04:13:00 2015-08-01 04:03:00 CEST--2015-08-01 04:13:00 CEST            2
#3 2015-08-01 14:00:00 2015-08-01 14:15:00 2015-08-01 14:00:00 CEST--2015-08-01 14:15:00 CEST            2
```