# Faster way to execute function than mapply in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data frames, `ord` with 15k rows

```
         uniq.id prev.ord.dt cur.ord.dt
           <chr>      <date>     <date>
1  4892267119791  2016-04-28 2016-06-09
2  7174853145105  2016-04-26 2016-05-10
3  9600318129252  2016-07-07 2016-07-11
4  7150993150290  2016-03-30 2016-04-13
5  3121040102603  2016-05-01 2016-05-18
6  4899102101891  2016-04-29 2016-05-08
7  7174853112259  2016-05-10 2016-05-24
8  4648283132540  2016-04-25 2016-05-09
9  9600318144830  2016-05-12 2016-05-19
10 9600318134838  2016-05-23 2016-06-06
...
```

and `dlvrd`. with 39k rows

```
uniq.id   dlvrd.dt dlvrd.qty
           <chr>     <date>     <int>
1  9600318114229 2016-02-24        10
2  2594775116151 2016-04-07        22
3  4935357145929 2016-05-26         6
4  4127487134929 2016-05-18         9
5  4935357144169 2016-05-10        62
6  1180975135573 2016-03-16        11
7  3121040102604 2016-06-17        22
8  1580171115586 2016-01-12       240
9  3011291147292 2016-03-25        12
10 4892267115584 2016-05-16        21
...
```

**EDIT:** There are about 2k total of the `uniq.id`, and each one has multiple delivery periods under it (assume for simplicity that a delivery period is indicated by `cur.ord.dt`). I need to aggregate the total quantity that was delivered for each `uniq.id` for each delivery period, but the method I'm currently using is taking ~35 minutes to run. I defined a custom function

```
add.dlvrd <- function(uniq, prev, cur) {
  require(dplyr)
  dlvrd <- get("dlv.data", envir = .GlobalEnv)

  dlvrd <- dlvrd %>% filter(uniq.id==uniq,
                            dlvrd.dt >= prev, 
                            dlvrd.dt < cur) %$% sum(dlvrd.qty) %>% return()
}
```

and then run `mapply`

```
ord$dlvrd.qty <- ord %$% mapply(add.dlvrd, uniq.id, prev.ord.dt, cur.ord.dt)
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

**Side note:** I'm aware that it's bad form to use "." in variable and function names instead of "_", but I don't have time to change it right now.

Comment: Could you make a small reproducible example? The data.table package has some tools for "interval joins", e.g., here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487949/how-to-perform-join-over-date-ranges-using-data-table (though that link is somewhat old)

Comment: @Frank The foverlaps function might work for me, but there may be multiple entries found in the "y", and I would want to sum these values instead of simply returning them

Comment: Yeah, I think it doesn't quite fit. The latest tool for interval joins, does allow for summing, though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38394201/ (found by following links in my last link). You'll probably need to learn some data.table syntax before using it, though.

Comment: Also, what is the quickest way to make a reproducible example?

Comment: The usual advice for making a good example is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/

Comment: Concerning your "side note" at the end: There are different opinions about the use of dots in variable and function names. The snake case is not generally preferred, and using dots is not generally considered bad style. To the contrary, some style guides expressly suggest using names the way you did and consider the snake case bad style. A topic of heated and mostly unnecessary debates...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL speak, you need a correlated aggregate subquery that would look like the following (which might be viable in [`sqldf`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html) package)

```sql
SELECT ord.uniqid, ord.prevorddt, ord.curorddt, 
       (SELECT SUM(dlvrd.dlvrqty) 
        FROM dlvrd.dlvrqty
        WHERE dlvrd.uniqid = ord.uniqid
        AND dlvrd.dlvrddt >= ord.prevorddt
        AND dlvrd.dlvrddt <= ord.curorddt) AS dlvrqty
FROM ord
```

The counterpart in base R would be a `sapply()` conditional, correlated sum:

```
ord$dlvr.qty <- sapply(1:nrow(ord), function(i) {
                     tempdf <- dlvrd[dlvrd$dlvrd.dt >= ord$prev.ord.dt[i] &
                                     dlvrd$dlvrd.dt < ord$cur.ord.dt[i] &
                                     dlvrd$uniq.id == ord$uniq.id[i],]
                     sum(tempdf$dlvrd.qty)
})
```

---

Though above solution resembles your original. From your posted data, a noticeable difference emerges between: 1) `mapply` and `dplyr` and 2) `sapply` and `base`:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(ord$dlvrd.qty <- with(ord, 
                                     mapply(add.dlvrd, uniq.id, prev.ord.dt, cur.ord.dt)))
#      min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
# 23.40284 24.21174 25.98971 25.6515 27.22191 32.95809   100

microbenchmark(ord$dlvr.qty <- sapply(1:nrow(ord), function(i) {
                               tempdf <- dlvrd[dlvrd$dlvrd.dt >= ord$prev.ord.dt[i] &
                                               dlvrd$dlvrd.dt < ord$cur.ord.dt[i] &
                                               dlvrd$uniq.id == ord$uniq.id[i],]
                                sum(tempdf$dlvrd.qty)
                            }))    
#      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# 6.426951 6.592485 7.157509 6.779431 7.124455 11.30587   100
```

And `vapply()` is slightly faster but may save in longer runs:

```
microbenchmark(ord$dlvr.qty <- vapply(1:nrow(ord), function(i) {
                               tempdf <- dlvrd[dlvrd$dlvrd.dt >=  ord$prev.ord.dt[i] &
                                               dlvrd$dlvrd.dt < ord$cur.ord.dt[i] &
                                               dlvrd$uniq.id == ord$uniq.id[i],]
                                        sum(tempdf$dlvrd.qty)
                             }, numeric(1)))
#      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# 6.395672 6.525357 6.912836 6.592966 6.865086 9.737148   100
```

Comment: What is order.dv in the first merge()?

Comment: When I tried this on my actual data, the `dlvrd.qty` came back as the same value for each `uniq.id`.

Comment: Sure, your objective was: *aggregate total quantity for each uniq.id* (between prev and cur dates). And uniq.id repeats for each order in distinct order in `ord`.

Comment: I have added a clarification to the objective above.

Comment: I got this working, thank you! I ended up getting access to an extra field in the dlvrd data field with the order date, making the match even simpler. You've also helped advance my knowledge of how to do this kind of thing in the future.

Comment: Excellent! Glad I could help a fellow R programmer.