# data.table join with date

Tags: r, date, join, data.table, posixct

hello im trying to extract some id with a group and Date in range

```
> d1
    id group       Date
 1:  1     A 2017-07-02
 2:  2     A 2017-07-04
 3:  3     A 2017-05-15
 4:  4     A 2017-08-02
 5:  5     B 2017-12-28
 6:  6     B 2015-07-02
 7:  7     B 2012-07-02
 8:  8     B 2018-07-02
 9:  9     C 2017-07-02
10: 10     C 2017-07-02
11: 11     C 2017-07-02
12: 12     C 2017-07-04
13: 13     D 2017-05-15
14: 14     D 2017-08-02
15: 15     D 2017-12-28
16: 16     D 2015-07-02
17: 17     E 2012-07-02
18: 18     E 2018-07-02
19: 19     E 2017-07-02
20: 20     E 2017-07-02

> d2
   group timestamp1 timestamp2
1:     A 2015-07-01 2017-07-20
2:     A 2020-07-12 2017-07-15
3:     B 2017-05-15 2020-05-22
```

and i want the id from d1 matching d2 date range and group

```
   group timestamp1 timestamp2 id
1:     A 2017-07-02 2017-07-02  1
2:     A 2017-07-04 2017-07-04  2
3:     A 2017-05-15 2017-05-15  3
4:     B 2017-12-28 2017-12-28  5
5:     B 2018-07-02 2018-07-02  8
```

i checked this [How to perform join over date ranges using data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487949/how-to-perform-join-over-date-ranges-using-data-table) i think it's the solution but ican't make it works.

Date, timestamp, timestamp2 are in `POSIXct`

please help :)

Comment: Except `id` == 6, all the values in `d1` seem to be in range of the values in `d2`, hence, your desired output isn't quite clear.

Comment: i want  something like  `group == group & Date >=timestamp1 & Date <=timestamp1` i hope it's better

Comment: I understand what you want and you can achieve this by doing something like `d2[d1, on = .(group, timestamp1 <= Date, timestamp2 >= Date), nomatch = 0L, mult = "first"]` (assuming you have correct `Date` classes) but your desired output doesn't make sense

Comment: sry i just failed at making a good date range in my exemple, it's working thx

Comment: Also, another way of achieving the same would be `d1[Date %inrange% d2[,.(timestamp1, timestamp2)]]`

Comment: it's forget to say that my d1 is a lot bigger than d2, when i do `d2[d1, on = .(group, timestamp1 <= Date, timestamp2 >= Date), nomatch = 0L, mult = "first"]` it return 0 line when ido `d2[d1, on = .(group, timestamp1 <= Date, timestamp2 >= Date)]` it give back a data with d2 size (it should be lot bigger

Comment: Then you don't have any matches. Either the date ranges don't overlap or the column classes aren't of `Date` class. Try making a proper reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

The OP has requested to do a *non-equi inner join* using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
d2[d1, on = .(group, timestamp1 <= Date, timestamp2 >= Date), nomatch = 0L]
```

> ```
>    group timestamp1 timestamp2 id
> 1:     A 2017-07-02 2017-07-02  1
> 2:     A 2017-07-04 2017-07-04  2
> 3:     A 2017-05-15 2017-05-15  3
> 4:     B 2017-12-28 2017-12-28  5
> 5:     B 2018-07-02 2018-07-02  8
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
d1 <- fread(
"rn id group       Date
 1:  1     A 2017-07-02
 2:  2     A 2017-07-04
 3:  3     A 2017-05-15
 4:  4     A 2017-08-02
 5:  5     B 2017-12-28
 6:  6     B 2015-07-02
 7:  7     B 2012-07-02
 8:  8     B 2018-07-02
 9:  9     C 2017-07-02
10: 10     C 2017-07-02
11: 11     C 2017-07-02
12: 12     C 2017-07-04
13: 13     D 2017-05-15
14: 14     D 2017-08-02
15: 15     D 2017-12-28
16: 16     D 2015-07-02
17: 17     E 2012-07-02
18: 18     E 2018-07-02
19: 19     E 2017-07-02
20: 20     E 2017-07-02", drop = 1L)[
  , Date := as.POSIXct(Date)]

d2 <- fread(
  "rn    group timestamp1 timestamp2
1:     A 2015-07-01 2017-07-20
2:     A 2020-07-12 2017-07-15
3:     B 2017-05-15 2020-05-22", drop = 1L)
cols = c("timestamp1", "timestamp2")
d2[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct), .SDcols = cols]
```

Comment: I just noticed that David Arenburg already posted the same approach in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46785611/data-table-join-with-date/48185497#comment80517996_46785611). Therefore, this answer is posted as community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Using **data.table**

```
df2$timestamp1 <- as.Date(df2$timestamp1, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
df2$timestamp2 <- as.Date(df2$timestamp2, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
df1$Date <- as.Date(df1$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

df1T <- data.table(df1, key = "group")
df2T <- data.table(df2, key = "group")
df3f <- df1T[df2T]
df3f[df3f$timestamp1 < df3f$Date & df3f$Date < df3f$timestamp2 , ]

   id group       Date timestamp1 timestamp2
1:  1     A 2017-07-02 2015-07-01 2017-07-20
2:  2     A 2017-07-04 2015-07-01 2017-07-20
3:  3     A 2017-05-15 2015-07-01 2017-07-20
4:  5     B 2017-12-28 2017-05-15 2020-05-22
5:  8     B 2018-07-02 2017-05-15 2020-05-22
```

You can also use a left join and filter in **dplyr** like so:

```
df3 <- df2%>%left_join(df1, by  = "group")%>%
  mutate(timestamp1 = as.Date(timestamp1, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
         timestamp2 = as.Date(timestamp2, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
         Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))%>%
         filter(timestamp1<Date&Date<timestamp2)%>%print()

  group timestamp1 timestamp2 id       Date
1     A 2015-07-01 2017-07-20  1 2017-07-02
2     A 2015-07-01 2017-07-20  2 2017-07-04
3     A 2015-07-01 2017-07-20  3 2017-05-15
4     B 2017-05-15 2020-05-22  5 2017-12-28
5     B 2017-05-15 2020-05-22  8 2018-07-02
```

Comment: Since version 1.9.6 (on CRAN 19 Sep 2015), setting keys is no longer required if the `on` parameter is used when joining `data.table`s.

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select df1.id, df1.Date, df2.* from df1
      inner join df2 on df1.'group' = df2.'group'
      where df1.Date between df2.timestamp1 and df2.timestamp2")
```

**Result:**

```
  id       Date group timestamp1 timestamp2
1  1 2017-07-02     A 2015-07-01 2017-07-20
2  2 2017-07-04     A 2015-07-01 2017-07-20
3  3 2017-05-15     A 2015-07-01 2017-07-20
4  5 2017-12-28     B 2017-05-15 2020-05-22
5  8 2018-07-02     B 2017-05-15 2020-05-22
```

**Data:**

```
df1 = read.table(text = "    id group       Date
                  1:  1     A 2017-07-02
                 2:  2     A 2017-07-04
                 3:  3     A 2017-05-15
                 4:  4     A 2017-08-02
                 5:  5     B 2017-12-28
                 6:  6     B 2015-07-02
                 7:  7     B 2012-07-02
                 8:  8     B 2018-07-02
                 9:  9     C 2017-07-02
                 10: 10     C 2017-07-02
                 11: 11     C 2017-07-02
                 12: 12     C 2017-07-04
                 13: 13     D 2017-05-15
                 14: 14     D 2017-08-02
                 15: 15     D 2017-12-28
                 16: 16     D 2015-07-02
                 17: 17     E 2012-07-02
                 18: 18     E 2018-07-02
                 19: 19     E 2017-07-02
                 20: 20     E 2017-07-02", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)

df2 = read.table(text = "   group timestamp1 timestamp2
1:     A 2015-07-01 2017-07-20
2:     A 2020-07-12 2017-07-15
3:     B 2017-05-15 2020-05-22", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
```