# R data.table sum of group subset using dates

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset like the following:

```
library(data.table)    
dt1 <- data.table(urn = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 4)),
                  amount = c(10, 12, 23, 15, 19, 42, 11, 5, 10),
                  date = as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-02-04",
                                   "2017-04-19", "2018-02-11", "2016-02-14",
                                   "2017-05-06", "2017-05-12", "2017-12-12")))
dt1
#    urn amount       date
# 1:   a     10 2016-01-01
# 2:   a     12 2017-01-02
# 3:   a     23 2017-02-04
# 4:   a     15 2017-04-19
# 5:   a     19 2018-02-11
# 6:   b     42 2016-02-14
# 7:   b     11 2017-05-06
# 8:   b      5 2017-05-12
# 9:   b     10 2017-12-12
```

I am trying to determine the cumulative value for a group over the preceding 12 months. I know I can use `shift` with `data.table` to scan backwards or forwards, the biggest challenge I can't get my head around is how to know how many records to sum when the number can change based on how many records each `urn` has.

The type of results I am looking for are:

```
dt1
#    urn amount       date summed12m
# 1:   a     10 2016-01-01        10
# 2:   a     12 2017-01-02        12
# 3:   a     23 2017-02-04        35
# 4:   a     15 2017-04-19        50
# 5:   a     19 2018-02-11        34
# 6:   b     42 2016-02-14        42
# 7:   b     11 2017-05-06        11
# 8:   b      5 2017-05-12        16
# 9:   b     10 2017-12-12        26
```

I'm preferably looking for a `data.table` solution due to the volume of my data, but am open to other options too if it is likely to be efficient over a table with about 12M records.

Comment: Where did you get the `34` in row `5` from??

Comment: That is the cumulative sum of rows `4` & `5` as they both fall within the same 12 month period.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As alternative to `foverlaps()`, this also can be solved by *aggregating in a non-equi join*:

```
library(lubridate)
dt1[, summed12m := dt1[.(urn, date, date %m-% months(12)), 
                       on = .(urn = V1, date <= V2, date >= V3), 
                       sum(amount), by = .EACHI]$V1][]
```

> ```
>    urn amount       date summed12m
> 1:   a     10 2016-01-01        10
> 2:   a     12 2017-01-02        12
> 3:   a     23 2017-02-04        35
> 4:   a     15 2017-04-19        50
> 5:   a     19 2018-02-11        34
> 6:   b     42 2016-02-14        42
> 7:   b     11 2017-05-06        11
> 8:   b      5 2017-05-12        16
> 9:   b     10 2017-12-12        26
> ```

`lubridate` is used for date arithmetic to avoid mishaps in case one of the dates is February, 29.

The essential part is the *non-equi join*

```
dt1[.(urn, date, date %m-% months(12)), 
    on = .(urn = V1, date <= V2, date >= V3), 
    sum(amount), by = .EACHI]
```

> ```
>    urn       date       date V1
> 1:   a 2016-01-01 2015-01-01 10
> 2:   a 2017-01-02 2016-01-02 12
> 3:   a 2017-02-04 2016-02-04 35
> 4:   a 2017-04-19 2016-04-19 50
> 5:   a 2018-02-11 2017-02-11 34
> 6:   b 2016-02-14 2015-02-14 42
> 7:   b 2017-05-06 2016-05-06 11
> 8:   b 2017-05-12 2016-05-12 16
> 9:   b 2017-12-12 2016-12-12 26
> ```

of which the last column is picked to create the new `summed12m` column in `dt1`.

#### Additional explanation

The OP has asked where `V1`, `V2`, and `V3` come from.

The expression `.(urn, date, date %m-% months(12))` creates a new data.table on the fly. (`.()` is an `data.table` abbreviation for `list()`). As no column names have been specified, `data.table` creates default column names `V1`, `V2`, etc.

Less sloppily, the expression can be re-written with explicitely named columns

```
dt1[.(urn = urn, end = date, start = date %m-% months(12)), 
    on = .(urn, date <= end, date >= start), 
    sum(amount), by = .EACHI]
```

Comment: I think this answer ends up being the best for my needs given the volume of data (although `foverlaps` is still pretty good), what I can't understand though is where `V1` & `V2` come from. I'd really like to be able to understand this better than I currently do

Comment: I have added an improved explanation.

Comment: That clarifies things. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

This is shouting for `foverlaps`. My first time using `foverlaps`, hence I am quite sure a few experts here can better wield the function. Here it goes:

```
dt1[, date2 := date]
rng <- dt1[, .(urn, enddate=date, 
    startdate=as.Date(paste(year(date)-1, month(date), mday(date), sep="-")))]
setkey(rng, urn, startdate, enddate)
foverlaps(dt1, rng, by.x=c("urn","date","date2"), type="within")[,
    sum(amount), by=.(urn, enddate)]

#    urn    enddate V1
# 1:   a 2016-01-01 10
# 2:   a 2017-01-02 12
# 3:   a 2017-02-04 35
# 4:   a 2017-04-19 50
# 5:   a 2018-02-11 34
# 6:   b 2016-02-14 42
# 7:   b 2017-05-06 11
# 8:   b 2017-05-12 16
# 9:   b 2017-12-12 26
```

Further reading:

1. [How to perform join over date ranges using data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487949/how-to-perform-join-over-date-ranges-using-data-table)
2. [roll join with start/end window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031/roll-join-with-start-end-window/25655497#25655497)

Answer (score 2):

```
dt1[, summed12m := {
        date_diff <- date - dt1$date
        sum(dt1$amount[date_diff >= 0 & date_diff <= 365 & urn==dt1$urn])
      }, 
      by = list(date, urn)]
```

Output is:

```
   urn amount       date summed12m
1:   a     10 2016-01-01        10
2:   a     12 2017-01-02        12
3:   a     23 2017-02-04        35
4:   a     15 2017-04-19        50
5:   a     19 2018-02-11        34
6:   b     42 2016-02-14        42
7:   b     11 2017-05-06        11
8:   b      5 2017-05-12        16
9:   b     10 2017-12-12        26
```

Sample data:

```
dt1 <- structure(list(urn = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
"b"), amount = c(10, 12, 23, 15, 19, 42, 11, 5, 10), date = structure(c(16801, 
17168, 17201, 17275, 17573, 16845, 17292, 17298, 17512), class = "Date")), .Names = c("urn", 
"amount", "date"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000027b0788>)
```

Comment: It's a great answer, but in testing on my large dataset it is rather slow. So far we're up to 15 mins and counting.