# Calculating the average of people in a hospital at every hour

Tags: r, date, average, tidyverse

I want to calculate the average number of people in hospital at every hour during the day with tidyverse. Can someone help?

Here it is the ID, Admissions (Adm) and Disc (Discharges).

```
ID = c(101, 102,103, 104, 105, 106, 107)

Adm = as.POSIXct(c("2012-01-12 00:52:00", "2012-01-12 00:55:00", "2012-02-12 
                    01:35:00", "2012-02-12 03:24:00", "2012-02-12 04:24:00", 
                    "2012-02-12 05:24:00", "2012-02-12 05:28:00"))

Disc = as.POSIXct(c("2012-01-13 02:00:00", "2012-01-13 02:59:00", "2012-02-12 
                     03:01:00", "2012-02-12 05:01:00", "2012-02-12 06:01:00", 
                     "2012-02-12 08:01:00", "2012-02-12 08:01:00"))

df = data.frame(ID, Adm, Disc)
```

Can someone help please!

Comment: Each row represents a patient?

Comment: yes, each row in ID is a patient, and the time when he was admitted and discharged.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487949/how-to-perform-join-over-date-ranges-using-data-table

Comment: Is it normal to find _Adm_ `2012-02-12` and for the same patient _Discharges_ `2012-01-12`?

Comment: I have corrected the dates. This is an example of data that I chosen not the real data I am working on. And, indeed I have mistaken. I have corrected everything now and hope there are no mistakes. Overall you got the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `tidyverse` approach :-

Basically hours between `Adm` & `Disc` are calculated using `seq` -

- e.g. hours between `Adm` = `2012-01-12 00:52:00` & `Disc` = `2012-01-12 02:00:00` for `ID` `101` would be `2012-01-12 00:00:00`, `2012-01-12 01:00:00` & `2012-01-12 02:00:00`.

These hours are concatenated using `paste` into a single column `hours_list` for each row and later separated into multiple rows using `separate_rows`.

Finally unique `ID` count is calculated by grouping on the calculated hours between admission and discharge timings.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Adm:Disc), funs(ymd_h(strftime(., format = "%Y-%m-%d %H")))) %>% #date-hour is separated from timestamp and then converted into POSIXct format
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(hours_list = paste(seq(Adm, Disc, by = "hour"), collapse = ",")) %>%     #hours between Adm & Disc are calculated and concatenated by ','
  separate_rows(hours_list, sep = ",") %>%                                        #calculated hours are separated into multiple rows
  mutate(hours_list = ymd_hms(hours_list)) %>%                                    #calculated hours are converted into POSIXct format
  group_by(hours_list) %>%
  summarise(patient_count = n_distinct(ID))                                       #unique patient count is calculated by grouping on calculated hours_list
```

which gives

```
   hours_list          patient_count
   <dttm>                      <int>
 1 2012-01-12 00:00:00             2
 2 2012-01-12 01:00:00             2
 3 2012-01-12 02:00:00             2
 4 2012-02-12 01:00:00             1
 5 2012-02-12 02:00:00             1
 6 2012-02-12 03:00:00             2
 7 2012-02-12 04:00:00             2
 8 2012-02-12 05:00:00             4
 9 2012-02-12 06:00:00             3
10 2012-02-12 07:00:00             2
11 2012-02-12 08:00:00             2
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107), Adm = structure(c(1326309720, 
1326309900, 1328990700, 1328997240, 1329000840, 1329004440, 1329004680
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Disc = structure(c(1326313800, 
1326317340, 1328995860, 1329003060, 1329006660, 1329013860, 1329013860
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Adm", "Disc"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

#   ID                 Adm                Disc
#1 101 2012-01-12 00:52:00 2012-01-12 02:00:00
#2 102 2012-01-12 00:55:00 2012-01-12 02:59:00
#3 103 2012-02-12 01:35:00 2012-02-12 03:01:00
#4 104 2012-02-12 03:24:00 2012-02-12 05:01:00
#5 105 2012-02-12 04:24:00 2012-02-12 06:01:00
#6 106 2012-02-12 05:24:00 2012-02-12 08:01:00
#7 107 2012-02-12 05:28:00 2012-02-12 08:01:00
```

Comment: Hey Prem - got an error - Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: 'to' must be a finite number

Comment: In your original data it seems that `Disc` is `NA` in few rows. You can test it using `df[is.na(df$Disc),]`. If this is the case then you may want to remove those rows and it can be done by adding `df %>% na.omit()` at the beginning of my code.

Comment: hello Prem, I identified the real issue within my data set . Indeed this is related to missing value. Thank you a lot, Prem. You rock :))

Comment: Glad that it helped :)