# How to group rows based on conditions set by another dataset?

Tags: r, data.table, bioinformatics

I've tried to code an answer to this based on similar questions, however I'm struggling to get any answers working exactly for my use case.

I have 2 genetic datasets (looking at positions of mutations in the genome).

These look like:

```
#df1:
Chromosome  Min     Max   Group
1           500     1000    1
1           400     1900    2
2           300     400     3
3           2000    2100    4
```

```
#df2
Gene    Chromosome  Position
Gene1          1    600
Gene1          1    650 
Gene2          1    1700
Gene3          2    350
Gene4          2    355
Gene5          2    450
Gene6          3    2050
```

I am looking to find which rows in `df2` belong to which `Group` in `df1`  - so I am coding to ask if a row in `df2` has a matching `Chromosome` number AND  the `Position` column value is inside the range between the `Max` and `Min` columns of `df1`, then if it is assign that row the same `Group` number as is in `df1`. I want this to also duplicate rows in `df2` if they appear in multiple Groups.

Expected output of the example is:

```
Gene    Chromosome  Position   Group
Gene1          1    600          1
Gene1          1    650          1 
Gene1          1    600          2
Gene1          1    650          2 
Gene2          1    1700         2
Gene3          2    350          3
Gene4          2    355          3 
Gene5          2    450          NA
Gene6          3    2050         4

#Gene1 enters both groups 1 and 2 as their Chromosome and Position fits in both those groups of df1
```

They key thing I'm trying to get that I am missing is that some groups in `df1` have overlap in their min-max range, but I still want each individual group to be kept and just Genes/rows of `df2` to be duplicated as  their position might match mulitple groups with overlap.

Currently I am trying to code this with:

```
df1$ID <- seq.int(nrow(df1))
df2$ID<- seq.int(nrow(df2))

df2[df1, Group := i.ID, on = .(Chromosome, Position > Min, Position < Max ) ]
```

For my example this outputs:

```
Gene  Chromosome Position  ID Group
Gene1   1           600     1   2
Gene1   1           650     2   2
Gene2   1           1700    3   2
Gene3   2           350     4   3
Gene4   2           355     5   3
Gene5   2           450     6   NA
Gene6   3           2050    7   4
```

So in this case because Groups 1 and 2 have an overlap in their min-max range, Group 1 has been lost from the output result. Is there another way I can code to avoid this and match rows but maintain all `Groups` despite any range overlaps?

I have tried other ways to code this with a similar question ([How to perform join over date ranges using data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487949/how-to-perform-join-over-date-ranges-using-data-table)) using `foverlaps()` but this also does not work as expected.

Input data:

```
df1 <-
structure(list(Chromosome = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Min = c(500L, 
400L, 300L, 2000L), Max = c(1000L, 1900L, 400L, 2100L), Group = 1:4, 
    ID = 1:4), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

df2 <-
structure(list(Gene = c("Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", 
"Gene5", "Gene6"), Chromosome = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), 
    Position = c(600L, 650L, 1700L, 350L, 355L, 450L, 2050L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df2[, Group := df1[.SD, 
                   on = .(Chromosome = Chromosome, Max > Position, Min < Position), 
                   toString(Group), 
                   by = .EACHI]$V1]

#     Gene Chromosome Position Group
# 1: Gene1          1      600  1, 2
# 2: Gene1          1      650  1, 2
# 3: Gene2          1     1700     2
# 4: Gene3          2      350     3
# 5: Gene4          2      355     3
# 6: Gene5          2      450    NA
# 7: Gene6          3     2050     4
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data.table` merge notation of `A[B,...]` performs a left join of B on A ... backwards to the eye. Its equivalents:

- base R: `merge(A, B, all.x = FALSE, all.y = TRUE, ...)`
- dplyr: `dplyr::right_join(A, B, ...)` or `dplyr::left_join(B, A, ...)`
- SQL: `... FROM B left join A ...`

With that, I suggest two steps:

1. Because the range-join causes one of your non-equi joining columns to be renamed, I'll save `Position` into a new variable and use that instead. It'll wash out.
2. Reverse the objects.

Therefore,

```r
df1[df2[,Pos0:=Position], on = .(Chromosome, Min < Pos0, Max > Pos0 ) ][,.(Gene,Chromosome,Position,Group)]
#      Gene Chromosome Position Group
#    <char>      <int>    <int> <int>
# 1:  Gene1          1      600     1
# 2:  Gene1          1      600     2
# 3:  Gene1          1      650     1
# 4:  Gene1          1      650     2
# 5:  Gene2          1     1700     2
# 6:  Gene3          2      350     3
# 7:  Gene4          2      355     3
# 8:  Gene5          2      450    NA
# 9:  Gene6          3     2050     4
```