# data.table join with conditions: keep all columns

Tags: r, join, merge, data.table

I have these two tables

```
library(data.table)
d = seq(0.1,1,by = 0.1)
n = length(d)
dtBig = data.table(id = rep(letters[1:2],each = n/2),
                   d1 = d,
                   d2 = d + 0.2,
                   i = 1:n)
dtSmall = data.table(id = rep(letters[1:2],each = 2),
                     d_start = c(0.2,0.65,0.15,1.1),
                     d_end = c(0.65,0.85,0.8,1.5))
```

I would like to do an efficient merge on `id` with two inequality conditions `d1 >= d_start` and `d2 <= d_end`.

The first method is time consuming when tables have many rows:

```
dtAll = merge(dtSmall, dtBig, by = "id", allow.cartesian = T)[d1 >= d_start & d2 <= d_end]
```

So I use 'on' operator:

```
dtAll2 = dtBig[dtSmall, on = .(id, d1 >= d_start, d2 <= d_end),nomatch = 0]
```

However, d1 takes values of d_start and d2 of d_end and I loose the values of d1 and d2.
So I made these commands:

```
dtAll2 = dtBig[dtSmall, on = .(id, d1 >= d_start, d2 <= d_end),nomatch = 0]
dtAll2[,`:=`(d_start = d1, d_end = d2)]
dtAll2[,`:=`(d1 = NULL, d2 = NULL)]
dtAll2 = dtAll2[dtBig[,.(i,d1,d2)],on = .(i == i),nomatch = 0]
```

verify that dtAll and dtAll2 are the same:

```
setcolorder(dtAll, names(dtAll2))
setkey(dtAll,i)
setkey(dtAll2,i)
all.equal(dtAll,dtAll2)
```

But I am sure there is a better way, any ideas ?

Comment: Your approach is how I've done it in the past, but I am following to see if there is a better way.

Comment: What if you renamed the inputs `dtBig[, c(.SD, .(d_start=d1, d_end=d2))][dtSmall, on = .(id, d_start >= d_start, d_end <= d_end), nomatch = 0]` for instance?

Comment: You could also explicitly select the source of your output variables: `dtBig[dtSmall, on = .(id, d1 >= d_start, d2 <= d_end), .(d1=x.d1, d2=x.d2, id=i.id, i=x.i, d_start=i.d_start, d_end=i.d_end), nomatch = 0]` - but neither of these options seems overly nice to me.

Comment: Maybe related? [Use `j` to select the join column of `x` and all its non-join columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329157/use-j-to-select-the-join-column-of-x-and-all-its-non-join-columns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `foverlaps` that is available `data.table` for this, and from your `d1 >= d_start & d2 <= d_end` we can tell that you are interested in those records in dtBig that are **within** the range of start/end in dtSmall, which can be provided in the `type` argument. You must use `setkey` on the `y` (second table, dtSmall). You do not have to use `by.y` as it defaults to your keys in y.

```
setkey(dtSmall, id, d_start, d_end)
dtAllF <- foverlaps(dtBig, dtSmall, by.x = c("id", "d1", "d2"), type = "within", nomatch = 0)
```

Results

```
dtAllF
# id d_start d_end  d1  d2 i
# 1:  a    0.20  0.65 0.2 0.4 2
# 2:  a    0.20  0.65 0.3 0.5 3
# 3:  a    0.20  0.65 0.4 0.6 4
# 4:  b    0.15  0.80 0.6 0.8 6
```

Check for equality

```
setcolorder(dtAllF, c("id", "i"))
identical(dtAll2, dtAllF)

# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I had tried to use foverlaps but foolishly thought it was not possible with an equality condition xD thanks again :)